# Convert JSON string to Map with any primitive type or JSONObject

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am trying to convert provided string (JSON) to Map<String,Any> so for example JSON can be like that (value can be any primitive type or a collection such as map set or array :

```
{
    "key": "thisIsMyKey",
    "value": false
}
```

So i did convert it using GSON with this little snippet:

```
return jsonMap?.let { Gson().fromJson(jsonMap, object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}.type) }
```

The issue i am having is now for following example if i want to pass value with JSONObject

```
{
    "key": "thisIsMyKey",
    "value": {
        "title": "this is title"
    }
}
```

It gets converted to one key and multiple "Any" values with string, but in this case i expect that value is than just one entry of <String, JSONObject), any tips how to achieve this one level too deep converting?

Comment: What is your expected result? Is it a `mapOf("key" to "thisIsMyKey", "value" to mapOf("title" to "this is title"))` or something else?

Comment: in second case its actualy "value" to JSONobject()

Comment: If you specify type as `HashMap<String, JsonElement>` you will get `mapOf("key" to JsonPrimitive("thisIsMyKey"), "value" to JsonObject().also { it.add("title", JsonPrimitive("this is title")) })`. Will it be good enough?

Comment: But in the first case where value is only boolean false i will get JSONElement too instead of String, Boolean ?

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by specifying expected type as `Map<String, JsonElement>`. Downside of this approach is that values of primitive types (`Number`, `String`, `Boolean`) would be wrapped into `JsonPrimitive`. If it's unacceptable, you may manually unwrap them:

```kotlin
val result = jsonMap?.let {
    Gson().fromJson<Map<String, JsonElement>>(jsonMap).mapValues { (_, v) -> deprimitivize(v) }
}

fun deprimitivize(e: JsonElement) = if (e is JsonPrimitive) e.getValue() else e

fun JsonPrimitive.getValue(): Any = when {
    isBoolean -> asBoolean
    isNumber -> asNumber
    else -> asString
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> Gson.fromJson(json: String): T = fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```